# Using name attribute with ngModel in a form tag, still getting error -"If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set..."

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-ngmodel

Following is my `html`:

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.adminVerificationEndDate" name="adminVerificationEndDate" 
           type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm"
           [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig" bsDatepicker [minDate]="currentDate" required/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have initialized all the variables used in my ts file. I have bound the model property within the form tag by using ngModel, I have also used the name attribute.

But still getting the error -**If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form-control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.**

What I am missing here?

I have also attached the screenshot of my console throwing that error.

[image: Error showing on console]

[image: the line of code where the error is generated]

Any kind of help/suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: please give you full code inside form

Comment: I am afraid that's a very long file. what you are suspecting from full form can you elaborate?

Comment: @TasnimFabiha see this link it will be helpful to u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069944/if-ngmodel-is-used-within-a-form-tag-set-name-or-set-standalone-error?rq=1

Comment: Are you using ngForm or Reactive Form ? Can you share the form tag code also in this question.

Comment: @TasnimFabiha try rebuilding your app the  ie. stop ng serve and start it again , your code will work in normal case seems like somethings wrong with compiler

Comment: @TasnimFabiha also if you could create a demo in stackblitz it would be great, so that we can check the code   along with the datepicker that you have used : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nym2ar

Comment: @JoelJoseph thanks for the suggestions, I have found the error in another line, and its a bit confusing that the compiler was showing error in some other line. thanks for the help btw :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you used,

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <input [(ngModel)]="model.adminVerificationEndDate" name="adminVerificationEndDate"
       type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm"
       [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig" bsDatepicker [minDate]="currentDate" required/>
   </div>
</div>
```

you have added name attribute in this form tag but the error is still showing. so, there is a possibility that **you have another form tag that doesn't have any name attribute**.

But the problem is in **console it will show the line number of first form tag** and yes, it is confusing.

to understand this properly please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48601195/1999720).

so, In your case specifically,

[image]
please see the last line of the console error. It denotes line number 140.

So, I assume **line 123 is ok** (green box).

you are probably overlooking that line. check that line 140 of html also if there is any name attribute.

Comment: yes, the error was in line number 140, where name attribute was missing. but 123 is not my first line of the form tag, not even the first input field where I used ngModel. I am not getting the fact that why compiler showed the error in other input fields rather than the actual one.

Answer (score 0):

use this code..

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="model.adminVerificationEndDate" name="adminVerificationEndDate" 
       type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm"
       [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig" bsDatepicker [minDate]="currentDate" required/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model.adminVerificationEndDate" name="adminVerificationEndDate" 
             type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm" #adminVerificationEndDate="ngModel" 
             [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig" bsDatepicker [minDate]="currentDate" required/>
```

Comment: whats the difference here?

Comment: #adminVerificationEndDate="ngModel" is the difference I guess